# Triangularization Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I was reading a proof about the triangularization theorem given in Shapiro's Linear Algebra and Matrices textbook. Here is the proof for reference[image]

I understand the basic gist of the proof, however, there is one thing that doesn't sit right with me. How are we able to justify that after constructing the invertible matrix $W$ as described, that $W^{-1} A W$ will take the form $$\begin{pmatrix} 
\lambda & * \\
0 & A_{22} \: 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you see what the first column of $AW$ is ? If so, do you see what the first column of $W^{-1}(AW)$ is ?

Comment: I actually do not see what the first column of $AW$ is. I know that the first column of $W$ is an eigenvector for $A$ though

Comment: By definition of matrix multiplication, the first column of $AW$ is exactly $AW_1$, where $W_1$ is the first column of $W$, which is here the eigenvector $w_1$. So, this gives $\lambda W_1$.

Comment: I see, so then the first column of  $W^{-1}(AW)$ will be  $W^{-1}(AW)_1 = W_1^{-1} \lambda W_1 = \lambda.$ Is that correct?

Comment: Be careful : on the LHS you have a column vector, on the RHS you have a scalar, so your equation can't be true. The first column you obtain is $W^{-1}(AW)_1=\lambda W^{-1}W_1=\lambda e_1$ where $e_1$ is the first column of the identity matrix (this comes from the identity $W^{-1}W=Id$).

Comment: That makes sense! thank you